# Given a weighted graph, dividing nodes into K subsets with a minimum value of maximum distance between two nodes in same subset

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given a weighted graph, I want to divide the nodes into K subsets such that each node appears in exactly one subset and also maximum distance between two nodes in the same subset becomes as minimal as possible. 
I don't want the algorithm to produce the best possible partitioning necessarily, instead I need an approximate approach with polynomial time complexity. 
I prefer to use an algorithm to execute within 10 minutes (but not restricted) on 1500 nodes and gives the partitioning near to best answer. 
I'm interested in any idea about this.

Comment: Do you know the range of K?